# Is it worthwhile, for performance reasons, to surround Apache mod_rewrite checks with Directives like Location, DirectoryMatch, etc?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, performance, mod-rewrite

I currently have a number of Apache rewrite rules using mod_rewrite (Apache 2.2).

When I turn on rewrite logging I see a number of evaluations of rewrite conditions for files that have no chance of being a match for the rewrite condition.

For example, if I have a series of rewrite conditions that have no chance of matching my file `/context/chet.js`, should I surround the entire block with some type of `<Location>` directive that would bypass all of the RewriteCond when I know none of them will match to improve performance?  Or are the rewrite checks fast/quick enough that doing so is not going to be worthwhile?  How many rewrite checks would it take to make a pre-evaluation with a directive like `<Location>` worthwhile?

```
[23/Sep/2013:12:04:31 --0400] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /context/chet.js
[23/Sep/2013:12:04:31 --0400] (3) applying pattern '.*' to uri '/context/chet.js'
[23/Sep/2013:12:04:31 --0400] (3) applying pattern '^/context/xyz' to uri '/context/chet.js'
[23/Sep/2013:12:04:31 --0400] (3) applying pattern '^/context/abc123' to uri '/context/chet.js'
[23/Sep/2013:12:04:31 --0400] (3) applying pattern '^/context/testService/(.*)$' to uri '/context/chet.js'
[23/Sep/2013:12:04:31 --0400] (3) applying pattern '^/context/detect/(.*)$' to uri '/context/chet.js'
[23/Sep/2013:12:04:31 --0400] (1) pass through /context/chet.js
```